# Reactivesearch without multi search

Tags: reactivesearch

Is it possible to use reactive search without the multi search api. I can not use the multi search api for my Elastic Search cluster.

Currently I've monkeypatched away the `_msearch?` part of the url and changed the content-type to `application/json` which works but it's not optimal.

Comment: Its not possible to turn it off currently I'm afraid. Is there any issue you see with using msearch?

Comment: Yes my issue it that my backend provides an endpoint which is not a direct url to the Elastic Search cluster. The backend authenticates the request and makes the request to Elastic Search with the params provided and the body and returns the response.


They currently does not support multi search in terms of the `_msearch?` param in the url and the indexed body.


IIRC reactive search did not support multi search up until v 2.5.0[issue](https://github.com/appbaseio/reactivesearch/issues/295) so it wouldnt be that much of a hussle to provide the multi search feature as a prop right?

Comment: It wouldn't be a small change since the internal architecture had to be modified quite a bit for msearch. Could you create an issue with your usecase? https://github.com/appbaseio/reactivesearch/issues/new

Comment: For future references: i've opened an issue [here](https://github.com/appbaseio/reactivesearch/issues/471)